# How to render a circle in pixijs

Tags: pixi.js

i'm banging my head to wall. I cannot render simple circle in pixijs. Any healp appreciated?

Playgroud link - [https://pixiplayground.com/#/edit/eE~VcTxQSEi_I_DZk6Agz](https://pixiplayground.com/#/edit/eE%7EVcTxQSEi_I_DZk6Agz)

Answer (score 5):

If you are just trying to render a circle, this is all you need:

```
var app = new PIXI.Application({
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  backgroundColor: 0x2c3e50
});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const gr  = new PIXI.Graphics();
gr.beginFill(0xffffff);
gr.drawCircle(30, 30, 30);
gr.endFill();
app.stage.addChild(gr)
```

Here is a working example: https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/5_EeuD2_YmdV8oleXRZ2P